# Is there a uniform ExcelExtractor class and a factory for both xls and xlsx files?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Is there a common class and an implementation of the [ExcelExtractor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/extractor/ExcelExtractor.html) interface that handles, uniformly, extraction of text from xls and xlsx sources?
Maybe, something in `ss` package.

I am looking for something that would allow me to do something like, but by getting the right implementation from the factory, based on the file type.

Right now, I am having to explicitly use the `org.apache.poi.hssf.extractor.ExcelExtractor`
for the xls files and `org.apache.poi.xssf.extractor.XSSFExcelExtractor` for xlsx.

For example, explicit approach for xls:

```
InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(path);
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new POIFSFileSystem(inp));
ExcelExtractor extractor = new ExcelExtractor(wb);

extractor.setFormulasNotResults(true);
extractor.setIncludeSheetNames(false);
String text = extractor.getText();
```

I can implement my own Factory, but before I do that I thought to ask to see if there is a common approach that handles both formats (that is what [ss](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hssf/eventusermodel/examples/XLS2CSVmra.java) package is for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options

First, if you really really want to stick with the old Apache POI text extractors, then use the [ExtractorFactory class](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/extractor/ExtractorFactory.html). That will identify the type, and create an extractor for you

However, the better option - [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org). Tika builds on top of POI (and lots of others), and gives you plain text extraction (+detection +xhtml +more!) from a wide range of file formats. You'd just call Tika, ask for the text, and get it back no matter the type. See [Tika examples like this one](http://tika.apache.org/1.10/examples.html#Parsing_to_Plain_Text) to get started